# Multiple MongoDb filters in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb.driver

To handle multiple MongoDb filters in C#, I had wrote below method;

```
        public string MultipleFilters(string collectionName, Dictionary<string, string> dictFilters)
        { 
            var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("", "");

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dictFilters)
            {
                filter = filter & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq(entry.Key, entry.Value);
            }

            var collection = this.database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);           
            var document = collection.Find(filter).First();

            return document.ToJson();
        }
```

But it throws the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("", "")` is a valid MongoDB filter which tries to find a document with an empty key and empty value ([example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VHa0kQwDVWO)),

it's better to use `Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty` instead.

Also you're running `.First()` on after `.Find()` method so you're assuming that there's always at least one value. That's fine if you want `Sequence contains no elements` to be thrown when something goes wrong however you can try to handle that more gracefully by using `.FirstOrDefault()`